# How do i draw percent on the progressBar1?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

```
private void NewsUpdate()
        {
            counter += 1;
            progressBar1.Value = counter;
            int percent = progressBar1.Value;
            progressBar1.CreateGraphics().DrawString(
                percent.ToString() + "%", new Font("Arial", (float)8.25, FontStyle.Regular),
                Brushes.Black, new PointF(progressBar1.Width / 2 - 10, progressBar1.Height / 2 - 7));
            //progressBar1.Refresh();
            label9.Text = counter.ToString();
            label9.Visible = true;
            if (counter == 10)
            {
                Extractions();
                counter = 0;
            }
        }
```

This way i see the percentages in the middle of the progressBar1 but it's blinking.
I tried to add progressBar1.Refresh(); before and after the Drawing tried Invalidate the progressBar1 but nothing help it's blinking.

This method NewsUpdate im calling it through a timer tick event that it's interval set to 1000ms

How can i make it smooth without blinking ?

EDIT

This is what i did i added a OnPaint override event:

```
protected override void OnPaint(PaintEventArgs e)
        {
            int percent = progressBar1.Value = counter;
            base.OnPaint(e);

            e.Graphics.DrawString(percent.ToString() + "%",
                SystemFonts.DefaultFont,
                Brushes.Black,
                new PointF(progressBar1.Width / 2 - (e.Graphics.MeasureString(percent.ToString() + "%",
                    SystemFonts.DefaultFont).Width / 2.0F),
                progressBar1.Height / 2 - (e.Graphics.MeasureString(percent.ToString() + "%",
                    SystemFonts.DefaultFont).Height / 2.0F)));

        }
```

An in the method i update in the timer i did on invalidate:

```
private void NewsUpdate()
        {
            counter += 1;
            this.Invalidate();
```

The problem now is that i see the percentages on the top of form1. How can i move the percent to be shown on the progressBar in the middle ?

[image: ProgressBar]

EDIT

I tried this one now:

```
protected override void OnPaint(PaintEventArgs e)
        {
            int percent = progressBar1.Value = counter;
            base.OnPaint(e);
            Graphics gr = e.Graphics;
            using (gr = progressBar1.CreateGraphics())
            {
                gr.DrawString(percent.ToString() + "%",
                    SystemFonts.DefaultFont,
                    Brushes.Black,
                    new PointF(progressBar1.Width / 2 - (gr.MeasureString(percent.ToString() + "%",
                        SystemFonts.DefaultFont).Width / 2.0F),
                    progressBar1.Height / 2 - (gr.MeasureString(percent.ToString() + "%",
                        SystemFonts.DefaultFont).Height / 2.0F)));
            }
        }
```

Now its on the progressBar but blinking again. The percentages are blinking.

Comment: Put the WPF TextBlock (instead of Label) control w/percentage completion outside the ProgressBar control. Rgds,

Comment: @AlexBell: He isn't using WPF.

Comment: You need to handle & draw in the `Paint` event.

Comment: Is this the OnPaint of the progressbar ?

Comment: Sara no. I created the OnPaint manualy on the form1 just added a method called it OnPain. progressBar dosent have any paint or onpain events. How can i make progressBar1 OnPaint event ?

Comment: What is the parent class of the progressbar, Is it UserControl? i mean does it inherit from any classes ?

Comment: Sara no the progressBar1 is from the form1 designer. I dragged the control to form1 designer.

Comment: I found this and it's good enough. http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/11839/Fully-Customizable-XP-Progress-Bar-with-examples

Comment: Why you won't to put simple label above your Progress bar?

Answer (score 0):

If you have set the maximum value of progress bar to 100 then you dont need to calculate percentage from progressbar value.

```
private void progressbar1_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
{
    StringFormat sf = new StringFormat();
    sf.Alignment = StringAlignment.Center;
    sf.LineAlignment = StringAlignment.Center;
    Font font = new Font("Arial", 8.25f, FontStyle.Bold, GraphicsUnit.Point);
    RectangleF rf = new RectangleF(0,0,progressbar1.Width, progressbar1.Height);
    e.Graphics.DrawString(progressbar1.Value.ToString("# %"), font, Brushes.Black,rf, sf);            
}
```

and place `progressbar1.Invalidate()` where you are updating `progressbar1.Value`

```
progressbar1.Value += 1;
progressbar1.Invalidate();
```

Comment: progressBar dosent have paint event.